# Is there any XMLStream reader in xquery?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to read an XML sequentially in xquery (MarkLogic DB) to identify start and end tags. Is there any stream reader available in xquery like Java's `XMLStreamReader`?

Comment: No there isn't: XQuery works on a tree model of data built by the XML parser, not on the raw lexical XML source. But if you explain what you are actually trying to achieve, then I'm sure we can help you find a way.

Comment: My aim is to find all the start & end elements. When I encounter a start element, I have some logic to do, similarly for end element.

Comment: If you mean start and end tags, then this is a non-starter. XQuery doesn't see tags, it sees nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Ash,

In XQuery, there is no function same like as in java XMLStreamReader. DOC() function in XQuery, read the xml doc but not read sequentially automatic, for this, you need to use below Query:

```
    let $result :=
       for $x in fn:doc()
        let $first-element :=name($x/*/*[1])
        let $last-element  :=name($x/*/*[last()])
           return fn:concat("First Element: ", "'", $first-element, "'", " Second element: ", "'", $last-element, "'")
    return $result
```